# how to check if a string has matching values with a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use a `for` loop and an `if` statement to compare if any values in the string match with any in the vector. It only outputs `"we have a match"` if the first character in `teststring` is in the vector. Basically, it seems like the searching stops if the first character value in `teststring` isn't in the `SpecialChars` vector. Sorry if that is confusing, I can't think of a better way to explain it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void test()
{
    std::vector<char> SpecialChars = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '8', '(', ')', '-', '+', '='};
    std::string teststring = "loll!@";
    bool test = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < SpecialChars.size(); i++)
    {
        if (teststring[i] == SpecialChars[i])
        {
            std::cout << "We have a match \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need two for loops. One for the string and one for the special characters. Unless you want to use C/C++ functions which already do that work (like `strchr()` in C and `find()` in C++).

Comment: It looks like it stops if the first character is a `!`. You are testing the first character in `teststring` against the first character of `SpecialChars`, then the second character in `teststring` against the second character of `SpecialChars`, and so on. You need either a nested loop or to use a search function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of may be what you're looking for.

Comment: A more efficient way to do this (without looping through the `SpecialChars` vector for every character) is to build a boolean lookup table indexed by character. Something like `bool isSpecial[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {}; for(unsigned char c : SpecialChars) isSpecial[c] = true;` ... Now you can check if a character is special in constant time, and that will work with a lambda combined with `std::find_first_of` or `std::any_of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`teststring` has a different length than `SpcialChars`, and `teststring` is shorter, so your `for` loop will go out of bounds of `teststring` when `i` reaches `6`, causing *undefined behavior*.

You need 2 loops, one to iterate `teststring`, and one to iterate `SpecialChars`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void test()
{
    std::vector<char> SpecialChars = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '8', '(', ')', '-', '+', '='};
    std::string teststring = "loll!@";
    bool found = false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < teststring.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < SpecialChars.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (teststring[i] == SpecialChars[j])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }

    if (found)
        std::cout << "We have a match\n";
}
```

You can simplify the outer loop by using a [`range-for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop, and eliminate the inner loop by using the standard [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void test()
{
    std::vector<char> SpecialChars = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '8', '(', ')', '-', '+', '='};
    std::string teststring = "loll!@";
    bool found = false;

    for (char ch : teststring)
    {
        if (std::find(SpecialChars.begin(), SpecialChars.end(), ch) != SpecialChars.end())
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        std::cout << "We have a match\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you could change `SpecialChars` into a `std::string` and use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) on it, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void test()
{
    std::string SpecialChars = "!@#$%^&8()-+=";
    std::string teststring = "loll!@";
    bool found = false;

    for (char ch : teststring)
    {
        if (SpecialChars.find(ch) != std::string::npos)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        std::cout << "We have a match\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a lookup table, like [@paddy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059358/73059460#comment129035648_73059358), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

void test()
{
    std::string SpecialChars = "!@#$%^&8()-+=";
    std::string teststring = "loll!@";
    bool found = false;

    bool isSpecial[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {};
    for(unsigned char ch : SpecialChars)
        isSpecial[ch] = true;

    for (unsigned char ch : teststring)
    {
        if (isSpecial[ch])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        std::cout << "We have a match\n";
}
```